# insert array to mysql db function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array where the keys represent each column in my database. Now I want a function that makes a mysql update query. Something like

```
    $db['money'] = $money_input + $money_db;

    $db['location'] = $location

    $query = 'UPDATE tbl_user SET '; 

            for($x = 0; $x < count($db); $x++ ){

            $query .= $db something ".=." $db something

            }

    $query .= "WHERE username=".$username." ";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$values = array();
foreach($db as $column => $value){
    $values[] = $column . "='" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
}
$query .= implode(',', $values);
```

But this will set all values as strings (not sure if MySQL makes automatic conversion), you might want to test with [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) first:

```
if(!is_numeric($value)) {
    $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
}
$values[] = $column . "=" . $value;
```

**Update:**

Whenever you set *string* values in a query, you have to put them into quotation marks. Hence you have to write:

```
$query .= "WHERE username='".$username."'";
```

(note the single quotation marks).

Using [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) can make the whole thing much clearer.

Comment: @DrColossos nope, it doesn't.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I know I'm gonna regret this but just for the fun: Thank you for that productive comment. I'm looking forward to reading your answer to this question.

Comment: Lol :) I seldom write answers and this question is definitely not one requiring my contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_keys](http://www.php.net/array_keys) to extract the names of the array elements and then simply use something like...

```
$query .= $keys[$x] . '="' . mysql_real_escape_string($db[$keys[$x]]) .'" ';
```

...within the for loop.

(I've presumed the presence of a...

```
$keys = array_keys($db);
```

... after you've defined the $db values in the above.)

That said, I'm really not sure I'd recommend such a "one size fits all" approach.

Answer (score 0):

something like [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4340):

```
function mysql_update_array($table, $data, $id_field, $id_value) {
    foreach ($data as $field=>$value) {
        $fields[] = sprintf("`%s` = '%s'", $field, mysql_real_escape_string($value));
    }
    $field_list = join(',', $fields);

    $query = sprintf("UPDATE `%s` SET %s WHERE `%s` = %s", $table, $field_list, $id_field, intval($id_value));

    return $query;
}
```

Please note that the code is NOT mine!

Comment: @2astalavista so you just down-voted the solution because you *think* the code is ugly?! :-)

Comment: by the way, why are my comments disappeared? :O

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $attr => $val)
    $items[] = "$attr='$val'";    
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table SET ".implode(',', $items));
```